# Change default "target" property name for dojox/mvc/at in rel:

Tags: dojo

I don't want to find "target" property name in parent, I want to find "mytarget" property name in parent.

Now I´m doing:

```
this.set("value", at("rel:", "title" ));
```

And it works with "target" property in parent. 
How can I change "rel" for use my own property name?

Comment: It's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve. Coud you provide more details?

Comment: I want to do a binding between an object and a TextBox. This code is into a extended "dijit/form/TextBox". I want to bind the value of the TextBox (this.set("value",... with the property "mytarget" of the parent widget. By default dojox/mvc/at is binding with "target" property.

Comment: So I assume that you have a textbox -> inside of widget -> inside of another widget. Is that right? And you want to bing textbox value not to containing widget, but to property of it's parent?

Comment: Yes, thats it. And now is working when the parent property name is "target". By default dojox.at uses "target" but I want to change the name of the parent property binded to the textbox.